# Kernel Surgery in a Script

Tags: text-processing, configuration, nvidia, kernel-modules

I'm writing a bash script to install a certain development environment on a computer. In order to do this I need to enable the CONFIG_USB_ACM module in the kernel. I am doing this through:

```
cd ~/l4t-kernel-surgery-kernel/kernel-4.4
zcat /proc/config.gz > .config

# PART I NEED IDEAS
vim .config # change the line that says CONFIG_USB_ACM=n to CONFIG_USB_ACM=m

make clean
make prepare
make modules_prepare
make M=drivers/usb/class
...
```

Would it work for me to append the =m line to the end of the config file? Will that overwrite the previous setting of =n? Is there a better way to edit the file in this way from bash?

Comment: Yeah I did, thanks for your answer btw. After closer inspection I realized that the =n line didn't even exist so I had to append it to the end of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | sed 's/CONFIG_USB_ACM=n/CONFIG_USB_ACM=m/'  > .config
```